# Seeing the NSLog for an app running directly in simulator, not via Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

Is there any way I can see the console logs of an app running in the iOS simulator when I do not run the code via Xcode? I am directly opening the app from within the simulator. Can I see the NSLog statements printing somewhere?

Comment: Organizer works for device & not for simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could manage to see the logs in "Console" application in MAC OS.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Here's a quote from [Tools Workflow Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/30-Ensuring_High_Quality_and_Optimal_Performance/quality_and_performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH20-SW6):

> When running your app in a simulator, you can access the app’s console
>   logs in the Console app (located in `/Applications/Utilities`).

Answer (score 3):

[From BYU CocoaHeads](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/different-nslog):

> **Redirected `NSLog()`**
>
> Occasionally, you may want to redirect your `NSLog()` output to a file so that you can examine it more conveniently. `NSLog()` works by outputting messages to `STDERR`, so all you need to do is redirect the `STDERR` stream to a file, and you're good to go. The following code will redirect it to a file on your desktop:
>
> ```
>     int fd = creat("/Users/dave/Desktop/my_log",
>                        S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
>     close(STDERR_FILENO);
>     dup(fd);
>     close(fd);
>     NSLog(@"this will be written to my_log");
> ```
>
> This will only affect `NSLog()` calls from your application.

Comment: Uhh, whoever wrote that article needs to work on their knowledge of POSIX; they are passively relying on the notion that the next open fd will be 2; this is not guaranteed to work and will actually do the wrong thing if another thread opens a file at the same time. The first `close` call and the `dup` should be replaced with `dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO)`.